# EF Core ExecuteSqlCommandAsync : Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1,2' to data type int

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.0, ef-core-2.0

I am running executing raw sql to delete some records that I added for the test. If I run the same query in management studio it works fine but when I run that query EF Core 2.0 it throws below error

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1,2' to data type int.'
```

Code

```
var idList = await Context.User.ToListAsync();
var ids = string.Join(",",idList.Select(x=>x.Id));
await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync($"Delete from User where Id in ({ids}) and RoleId = {contact.RoleId}");
```

Query executing 
`Delete from sale.WatchList where OfferId in (1,2) and UserId = 9`

Could anybody please advise on what wrong with the above code.

Thanks

Comment: A single string *containing* commas is *not* the same thing as multiple strings (or multiple integers) *separated* by commas. As true in SQL as, well, most other languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EF Core will transform interpolated strings into queries with parameters to create reusable queries and protect against SQL Injection vulnerabilities. See:  [Raw SQL Queries - EF Core - Passing Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#passing-parameters)

So

```
$"Delete from User where Id in ({ids}) and RoleId = {contact.RoleId}"
```

is transformed into

```
   Delete from User where Id in (@ids) and RoleId = @RoleId
```

With SqlParameters bound.

If that's not what you want, just build the SQL Query on a previous line.

Comment: though this creates warning

Answer (score 1):

This will not work. You have to write dynamic query. Please try like below one

```
var idList = await _dataContext.User.ToListAsync();
            var ids = string.Join(",", idList.Select(x => x.Id));
            await _dataContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync($"execute('Delete from User where Id in ({ids}) and RoleId = {contact.RoleId}')");
```

Comment: throws error : Must declare the scalar variable "@p0".

Answer (score 0):

although accepted answer does work, it creates lot of warnings so for now I am using what @Abu Zafor suggested with small change/fix

`await _dataContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync($"execute('Delete from User where Id in ({ids}) and RoleId = {contact.RoleId}')",ids,contact.RoleId);`